# Display Backbone model nested attributes in itemview

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Initially my Backbone model

```
 [
   {
        "id" : 1,
    "author" : "CA",
    "city": "LA",
        "Num_of_books": "5"
   },

   {
        "id": 2,
    "author":"John",   
    "city": "AM",
    "Num_of_books": "10"
   }
 ]
```

I am passing collection to a layoutout view which has composite view and itemview in composite view is like

```
 var View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'option',
    constructor: function(options) {
        this.attributes = {
            value: options.model.id
        };
        console.log(options);
        Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    template: _.template("<%= author %>")
 });
```

This gives me a

```
   <option value="idValue"> Author Name </option>
```

Now I need to change my json format to a nested (object instead of array) so id is key. For example

```
  {
       "1": {
        "author" : "CA",
    "city": "LA",
        "Num_of_books": "5"
       },

       "2": {
        "author":"John",   
    "city": "AM",
    "Num_of_books": "10"
      }
  }
```

Now how can I access my model attributes in item view so I can achieve thing like

```
  <option value="idValue"> Author Name </option>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way?  I understand why you did it but you know you can point to the specific id in a collection by using underscore right?  "_.findWhere( this.attributes, { id: idValue })".  Leaving a collection as an array is helpful because it imposes an order of items.  Also hijacking the constructor is a little hacky.  "onBeforeRender" doesn't suffice?

Comment: @josephnvu Ya seems like should leave collection array of models. Will make life easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally this data should be a collection, not a model. To use it in this way goes against the patterns in place for Backbone & Marionette and will cause all kinds of maintainability headaches later.

Consider something like this:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // .. book model config
});

var BookShelf = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book
});

var BookOption = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'option',
    template: _.template('<%= author %>'),
    attributes: function() {
       return {
         value: this.model.id
       }
    }
});

var BookList = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'select',
    itemView: BookOption
});

// ------ 

var bookshelf = new BookShelf();

bookshelf.add([{
    "id": 1,
        "author": "CA",
        "city": "LA",
        "Num_of_books": "5"
},{
    "id": 2,
        "author": "John",
        "city": "AM",
        "Num_of_books": "10"
}]);

var bookList = new BookList();
```

Comment: couldn't agree more. After thinking a while it seems life will be much more easier if I go with my original json format.